# Rotating an object and its 'children'

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

Right now I'm rotating an object, lets call it 'mainBody' but attached to the mainBody are several attachments and when I rotate my mainBody they are supposed to rotate along as well, but right now they don't. I'm not using a parent/child system. The main body has an array of it's attachments and draws them in the mainBody draw function.

The glPopMatrix() from the main body is done after the equipment items are drawn.

I know I managed to do this in the past with pushMatrix(); and popMatrix(); But now it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using c++, opengl, and glm.

Here is some code that shows you what I have right now:

```
{

    setupStartModelMatrix(); //<---- Has glPushMatrix();
    setupModelviewMatrix();  //<--- has all the gml stuff
    drawMainBody();

    }

    if(mNumberOfEquipementOwned != 0)

    {
        for(int i = 0; i < mNumberOfEquipementOwned; i++)
        {
            //obj is retrieved with a function 
            obj->render();
        }
    }

    setupEndModelMatrix();  // <--- Has glPopMatrix(); 
}
```

And the glm code

```
void GameObject::setupModelviewMatrix()
{
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.f);

    glm::mat4 Model = glm::scale( glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f)); 
    glm::mat4 ViewTranslate = glm::translate( glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(mPosition.x, mPosition.y, mPosition.z)); 
    glm::mat4 ViewRotateX = glm::rotate( ViewTranslate, mRotation.x, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    glm::mat4 ViewRotateY = glm::rotate( ViewRotateX, mRotation.y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    glm::mat4 View = glm::rotate( ViewRotateY, mRotation.z, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)); 

    glm::mat4 MVP = View * Model;

    glUniformMatrix4fv( 0, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP)); 

    glLoadMatrixf(glm::value_ptr(MVP));
}
```

And the draw equipement code

```
void Gun::render()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    setupModelviewMatrix();
    mMesh->render();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: When are you calling setupModelviewMatrix again inside your `Gun::render()`? You're obliterating any outstanding rotations. Or else how do you plan to get the rotation from the parent if you erase the parent's matrix?

Comment: @Tim I'm sorry, I don't fully understand what you mean. Are you telling me I should re move the setupModelvieuwMatrix(); inside the drawing function of the gun?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand your logic. You make clear that this is *not* a parent/child system, but I don't know why you think that your children objects should be rotated by the parent, if they use two completely independent matrices. I'm sure you can find many different examples of this kind of parent/child drawing in opengl, just look up any sun/earth/moon example.

Comment: @Tim That is because the attachments on the main body have to move along with the main body, the reason why I have two matrices is because I thought that is how this is supposed to work. Also if I remove the matrix call belonging to the equipment, the equipment becomes invisible.

Also I couldn't find an example for this and I will now look into this , Sun/Earth/Moon example.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not being clear. Yes, you need two matrices, but the child matrices should be derived from the parent's matrix. Your child matrix seems to be created without any input from the parent's position or rotation.

Comment: @Tim Ah, I see. So... probably a stupid question... but.. how do I do that?"

Comment: Check out this page: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html. Scroll down to the section titled "Examples of Composing Several Transformations", I think it should be relevant to you. Note that you don't have to use the **gl** commands here, you can easily apply the same concepts to your glm matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of Tim I noticed my matrix wasn't passed trough too the others. When I finally understood what he was saying it's a easy fix so 100% of the props go to him.

Now the code for anyone who might need it.

```
{
    glm::mat4 startingModel(1.0);

    setupStartModelMatrix();
    startingModel = continuedModelvieuwMatrix(startingModel);
    drawMainBody();
    }

    if(mNumberOfEquipementOwned != 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < mNumberOfEquipementOwned; i++)
        {
            //obj is retrieved with a function 
            obj->render(startingModel);
        }
    }

    setupEndModelMatrix();  // <--- Has glPopMatrix(); 
}
```

And the glm code

```
glm::mat4 GameObject::continuedModelvieuwMatrix(glm::mat4 startingModel)
{
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::scale( glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f)); 
    glm::mat4 ViewTranslate = glm::translate( startingModel, glm::vec3(mPosition.x, mPosition.y, mPosition.z)); 
    glm::mat4 ViewRotateX = glm::rotate( ViewTranslate, mRotation.x, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    glm::mat4 ViewRotateY = glm::rotate( ViewRotateX, mRotation.y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    glm::mat4 View = glm::rotate( ViewRotateY, mRotation.z, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)); 

    glm::mat4 MVP = View * Model;

    glUniformMatrix4fv( 0, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP)); 

    glLoadMatrixf(glm::value_ptr(MVP));

    return MVP;
}

void GameObject::setupStartModelMatrix()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

And the draw equipement code

```
void Gun::render(glm::mat4 startingModel)
{
    glm::math4 tempModel;
    tempModel = continuedModelvieuwMatrix(startingModel);
    mMesh->render();
}
```

And thats about it.
I'm not 100% sure if this code works as I had to fix it for my self in a different way because of my object construction but this should at least give a good head start for anyone with the same problem.

Also no glPopMatrix() or glPushMatrix() is required to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are calling `glPushMatrix()`, rotating, drawing your main body, calling `glPopMatrix()`, then drawing the attachments.  If this is true, move the `glPopMatrix()` call to after drawing the attachments.

Comment: Ah yes I should have mentioned this, I have the glPopMatrix of the main body behind the drawing of the atachements.